# the most efficient way to merge the range group in r?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

```
   Age_Group Region  Population
   <fct>     <fct>        <int>
1 0-4       ENGLAND    3384925
2 5-9       ENGLAND    3497402
3 10-14     ENGLAND    3166038
4 15-19     ENGLAND    3120730
5 20-24     ENGLAND    3526141
6 25-29     ENGLAND    3831624
7 30-34     ENGLAND    3757400
8 35-39     ENGLAND    3642643
9 40-44     ENGLAND    3442758
10 45-49     ENGLAND    3850108
```

Hey guys do you have the most efficient way to merge the age group by different intervals, like 5 years old or 10 years old to form the list below.

```
       Age_Group Region  Population
   <fct>     <fct>        <int>
1 0-9       ENGLAND    xxx
2 10-19     ENGLAND    xxx
3 20-29     ENGLAND    xxx
...
```

Comment: Just aggregate by every two rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` possibility

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(grp = rep(1:(nrow(.)/2), each = 2)) %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%
    mutate(
        Age_Group = paste(Age_Group, collapse = ":"),
        Age_Group = gsub("-\\d+:\\d+", "", Age_Group)) %>%
    mutate(Population = sum(Population)) %>%
    slice(1) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-grp)
## A tibble: 5 x 3
#  Age_Group Region  Population
#  <chr>     <fct>        <int>
#1 0-9       ENGLAND    6882327
#2 10-19     ENGLAND    6286768
#3 20-29     ENGLAND    7357765
#4 30-39     ENGLAND    7400043
#5 40-49     ENGLAND    7292866
```

Explanation: As mentioned by @DavidArenburg, we group entries by every two rows, create a new `Age_Group` label by combining `Age_Group` entries from every two rows, and then aggregate `Population` entries. Most of the work comes about from creating the new `Age_Group` labels.

Comment: Glad to help @ZakkYang; to create the new group labels we `paste` entries from every two rows together (giving e.g. `"0-4:5-9"`); we then remove the "middle bit" using `gsub("-\\d+:\\d+", "", ...)` where the regular expression `"-\\d+:\\d+"` matches a `-` followed by >=1 digits followed by `:` followed by >= 1 digits, i.e. `"-4:5"`. That leaves the required string `"0-9"` for the first new `Age_Group` label. Does that clear things up?